# VB.Net returning file to browser after button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have Asp.Net HTML that looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="Button1" type="button" runat="server" value="Run Report" />
    <span id="span1" runat="server"></span>
</form>
```

The VB looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_ServerClick(...) Handles Button1.ServerClick
    ...
    Dim dataOut = "some text"
    span1.InnerHtml = dataOut
End Sub
```

How do I change this code such that when the user presses the button a file is downloaded that contains "some text" rather than it being displayed on the screen.

Comment: You'll need to set the ContentType header to text/plain, and something else for ContentDisposition (I think) and then don't output HTML, just the raw dataOut. That should give you some clues on what to search for.

Comment: The easiest would be to instead of returning it from your button click, then onclick redirect to a generic handler (.ashx file), as you there have more control over the returning context and basically can dump the file stream into the context output stream